# Return tuple with value in list

Tags: python, list, tuples, namedtuple

I have this list of errors with their associated codes and descriptions:

```
Exception = namedtuple("Exception", "code name description")
exceptions = [
    Exception(1, "ILLEGAL FUNCTION", "Definition 1"),
    Exception(2, "ILLEGAL DATA ADDRESS", "Definition 2"),
    Exception(3, "ILLEGAL DATA VALUE", "Definition 2")
]
```

I would like a function that retrieves the exception with code==exception_code. I've searched around and the closest I could come up with is this:

```
# Returns the Exception tuple corresponding to the exception_code
def getException(self):
    return [item for item in exceptions if item[0] == self.exception_code]
```

This works but it's actually **returning a list**. My experience with Python is quite poor and I can't figure out how to simply **return the tuple instead**

NB: There will always be exactly one tuple with code == exception_code

Sample output of `print x.getException` with my current `getException`:

```
[Exception(code=2, name='ILLEGAL DATA ADDRESS', description='Definition 2')]
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead?

Comment: What? What use would that be? Also, if you don't want a list, why use a list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, you're better off making exceptions a dict:

```
exceptions = {
    1: Exception(1, "ILLEGAL FUNCTION", "Definition 1"),
    2: Exception(2, "ILLEGAL DATA ADDRESS", "Definition 2"),
    3: Exception(3, "ILLEGAL DATA VALUE", "Definition 2")
}
```

From here, your `getException` function becomes trivial:

```
def getException(code):
    return exceptions[code]
```

... and you have to wonder whether the function call looks better than just inlining :-)

Comment: Thanks this looks much better, will try it out and give you the point